# UIWebView - Frame displaying current page/total pages

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm working with UIWebView to load a PDF file. Right now it displays a frame at the top left corner showing the current page and the amount of pages. Is there any way to change the location of this frame?